# I can't open a program in WINE, it says that "the archive is corrupted" what do I do?

Tags: wine

I am trying to open up a `.exe` file in `wine` but when I type in the code it says the archive is corrupted (side note: Yes, I did delete the file and redownload it, that was my first reaction). I typed in the code just like the [help Ubuntu website](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Wine) said. I did the `wine` configuration, then `cd`ed into my desktop where my file was. But, when I typed `wine xsplit.exe` it came up with an error saying `this archive is corrupted`.

Comment: What "code" did you type in?

Comment: I typed 
cd Desktop
wine Xsplit.exe

Answer (score 0):

The problem you are probably having is that Ubuntu is trying to open the exe with the Archive Manager instead of with Wine. To fix this, just find the file in the file manager, right click on it, go to "Properties", click on the "Open with" tab, click on "Wine Windows Program Loader" and click on "Set as default". The exe files should now open with Wine when you double click on it.

Comment: Thanks, but wine is already the default, any other suggestions?

Comment: @AndrewSchalk Just looked at those instructions, they are a few years outdated. You just need to open the exe in the file manager.

Comment: I feel stupid for asking, but how do I do that?

Comment: @AndrewSchalk Just double click. If it still doesn't work, right click, go to "Open with" and click on Wine.

Comment: It still says it is corrupted, that was the first way I tried to open it before I found those instructions.

Comment: @AndrewSchalk Then it might be a problem with the exe itself. Could you give me a link to the file?

Comment: https://www.xsplit.com/download I have used this program on windows and it worked by the way.